# How to wait for results from a celery task in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery, celery-task

I have a celery task which sends data to another service. I have added the celery task `send_inventory_request` into `RequestSupplyStock` class based view. when I make a post I should first get results from celery task and then continue and return a response. I would like to first wait for the result from celery task and then return response from the post method which is the proper way to achieve this.

```
@app.task
def send_inventory_request(payload,token):
    auth = {'authorization':token}
    HEADERS.update(auth)
    url = PROCUREMENT_SUPPLY_STOCK_REQUESTS_URL
    res = requests.post(url,json=payload,headers=HEADERS)
    inventory_request_data = res.json()
    x= logger.info('Supply Stock Request {0} + {1}'.format(payload,token))
    print(x)
    return inventory_request_data
```

#### View

```
class RequestSupplyStock(generics.CreateAPIView):

      def post(self, request, format=None):
          ........

          send_inventory_request.delay(payload,get_token(request))

          .........
          return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: The *whole point* of Celery is so that you don't have to wait for long running tasks. If you need to wait, don't use Celery, do it directly in the view.

Comment: If you dependent on celery task result then surely there is no use of celery task there. But if you need to do for some exceptional case, just simply call that task without .delay . what I want to mean `  send_inventory_request.(payload,get_token(request))`.  This will return back you result.

Comment: I'm required to send items to another service my approach is to use tasks to send stock requests to another service. I absolutely agree that I don't need to wait for the results but I can have them queued and make them retry if there is a problem.

Comment: Then why not simply use try , except block or retry decorator if you don't receive your desire response, just simply retry for your pre-define maximum retry limit.

Comment: The proper solution if you want to use a celery task is to return the task id as the reponse value and provide another entry point to get the task's status (and results once done) - the client will be responsible for polling this other entry point.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Can you share with us how to do what you describe as an answer? Seems like the correct answer to the question in the title. But I don't really understand how to implement it.

Comment: @CarlKroegerIhl quite simply: first view launches the task and returns the task id as part of the response. Second view takes a task id, checks the task status, and returns it, including results when the task is done. The client first calls first view, locally stores the task id, and then uses it to poll the second view.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid use case! You may want to queue requests to an external service to control load and retry in case of failure as the OP says. For quick tasks it may also be reasonable for the client to wait a few seconds and get the result right away instead of implementing an entire polling mechanism on both sides with extra db hits, etc.

Answer (score 7):

You can use celery [wait](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.wait) , but it's not recommended

> Waiting for tasks within a task may lead to deadlocks. Please read
>   Avoid launching synchronous subtasks.

```
task = send_inventory_request.delay(payload,get_token(request))
result = task.wait(timeout=None, interval=0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

As others already mentioned in the comment, waiting for the result in synchronous manner defeats the purpose of using celery but if you still need to wait for the result then don't `delay`.

Just call the task like a normal method and it will run synchronously and return the result:

```
send_inventory_request(payload,get_token(request))
```

Comment: It's true , I think I will avoid this approach and read more about celery from the documentation.

Comment: This would work unless you need the task to be executed on a different worker. In that case, you have to use the delay / wait approach, otherwise the task would be executed locally.

Answer (score 0):

After your question and examples I have a couple insight.

But main problem It's out of understanding full architecture of the project.

I can't understand from what point you want listen a task status.

- Do you want listen from celery task?

  It's not the right solution. All what you can check it's a - Task created and successfully saved in queue.
- If you task more difficult and need more prediction control, you can use Canvas:
  https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#signatures

  You can use this task.id and checking it whenever you want
- If you use flower that's simplify all processes, because this lib has HTTP API:
  https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#get--api-tasks

One solution we can produce only know full picture.

Hope I'm help in something